# Why the use of 'ing' in this case?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

Context is a headline at NY times:

'Militia fighters in the Afar region of Ethiopia, which is being drawn into the conflict with neighboring Tigray.'

why not 'neighbor' instead of 'neighboring'??  As I can perceive the intend of the author is to use neighboring as an adjective. Unless I've perceived it all wrong

Comment: Yes, it is an adjective - it's a shorter way of saying _...with the neighboring country, Tigray_

Comment: [correction: as I perceive the intention of the author]

Comment: Your cited context is ***definitely not*** "a headline at NY times". Newspaper headlines almost ***never*** include words like ***which*** (a purely "grammatical" word required by *syntax*, which has little or no *meaning* as conveyed by ["content" words](https://www.teachingenglish.org.uk/article/content-words#:~:text=Content%20words%20are%20words%20that,prepositions%20are%20usually%20grammatical%20words.)).

Comment: what do you mean by: 'conveyed by "content" words"@FumbleFingers

Comment: I agree. This can't possibly be a NY Times headline. Where's the passive voice and the disdain for America? It's far too neutral. :)